# Query the database for laptops with price close to entered price

Tags: mysql

We are now doing embedded mysql queries for a small local website. I am wondering how I might do this query "Ask the user for a price and find the PC whose price is closest to the desired price. Print the maker, model number, and speed of the PC."

How might I find the pc with the price closest to the entered price from the user? 
I know I need to do a natural join between product and pc, something along these lines

```
SELECT maker, model, speed FROM 
(SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc) AS t1 
WHERE price (is close to) '$p';
```

Relations:

```
product(maker, model, type(pc, printer, laptop))
pc(model, price, speed, ram, hd size)
```

Comment: Set range or will the range be adjustable?

Comment: You could compute `ABS(price - $P) as pricedifference`, `order by pricedifference`

Comment: So in my query would be something as such "SELECT maker, model, speed FROM (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc) AS t1 ABS(price - '$p') AS priceDif ORDER BY priceDif;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an offset variable by taking the price and subtracting the inputed price. Make this an absolute (no negatives) then order by this and limit

```
SELECT product.maker, pc.model, pc.speed, ABS(pc.price - '$p') AS offset FROM pc LEFT JOIN product ON pc.model=product.model ORDER BY offset ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT maker, model, speed FROM 
( SELECT model FROM pc NATURAL JOIN product )
WHERE price
BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided very good schema info, so I have assumed that the tables join on the model column.

```
select p.maker, pc.model, pc.speed
from product p
inner join pc on p.model = pc.model
order by abs(pc.price - '$p')
limit 10
```

Also, I don't know how to eliminate the product you are comparing from the results list. It would probably be something like:

```
select p.maker, pc.model, pc.speed
from product p
inner join pc on p.model = pc.model
where pc.model <> '$model'
order by abs(pc.price - '$p')
limit 10
```